# How can i convert pointer-method of some class to pointer-function?

Tags: c++, pointers, callback, function-pointers, c2664

Greating everybody! I have a function-pointer method

```
int Myclass::*myMethod(char* a,char* b){
  //some code
}
```

And try to run it

```
bool Myclass::myMethod2(){
    AnotherClass *instance = AnotherClass:getInstance();
    instance-> addParams(&myMethod);
    return true;
}
```

AnotherClass - this class in another dll. AnotherClass definition

```
class AnotherClass
{
    //friend class Myclass;
public:
    static AnotherClass* getInstance();
    void addParams(int (*myMethod)(char*, char*) =0);
       //I try so void addParams(int (Myclass::*myMethod)(char*, char*) =0);
};
```

*And have error C2664.* Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int Myclass::* (__cdecl *)(char *,char *)' to 'int (__cdecl *)(char *,char *).

Hm.. What should i do?

Comment: It's impossible to convert a member function pointer to a non-member function pointer. What is it that you're really trying to do here? There might be a better way to do what you want.

Comment: `AnotherClass` looks badly-designed, since it takes just a function pointer, with no context belonging to the caller. Your caller apparently wants to provide some context (when calling a non-static member function `MyMethod` on a particular instance of `Myclass`, you need something for `this` to point to). C-style callback interfaces usually have a user data pointer for this, in C++ you can do the same, or use polymorphism. Depending how important the dll boundary is, you could perhaps make `addParams` a template.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling "bad function cast" warning](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676764/disabling-bad-function-cast-warning)

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

The `addParams()` method needs a function that accepts two `char*` arguments.

`Myclass::myMethod` accepts two `char*` arguments *and a* `Myclass` *object*.

There's no way to make the two compatible.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: I misread your question slightly, and didn't notice the bit about the DLL - but one and three still applies if you have control over the DLL, and have the desire to modify it.  If not, all you can do is number two.

---

In this case there are three things you could do:

One, change the way your `AnotherClass` is designed by declaring `addParams` like so:

```
void addParams(int (Myclass::*)(char*, char*) =0);
```

Two, you could make `Myclass::myMethod()` a static member, and then your original declaration of `addParams` would work.

Three, you could use a library like boost to bind the method as follows:

```
bool Myclass::myMethod2(){
    AnotherClass *instance = AnotherClass:getInstance();
    instance-> addParams(boost::bind(&Myclass::myMethod, this));
    return true;
}

class AnotherClass
{
    //...
    void addParams(boost::function<int(char*, char*)>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking the method from inside an instance of an object. (Assuming **Myclass::myMethod2()** is not static)

You can call the method from this:

```
instance-> addParams(&(this->myMethod));
```