# C/C++ casting void* to int ( * () ) (int,...);

Tags: c++, c, pointers, function-pointers

How can I cast `void*` to `int ( * () ) (int,...)`?

The `void*` is coming from a `dlsym`. This code isn't compiling:

```
typedef  int ( *PSYS () ) (int,...);
PSYS getf =  (PSYS) dlsym(lib, "function" );
```

Comment: why do you wanna cast `void *` to other type?

Comment: @haccks Because a `void*` is what is returned by `dlsym`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq; Should't it converted to that type implicitly? (Don't know much about this).

Comment: [tag:c] or [tag:c++]? The answer is different for different languages.

Comment: @haccks 1- The conversion from void* to function pointer is undefined in standard C, so it is not going to happen implicitly. 2- Even conversions from function pointer to function pointer do not happen implicitly on application (they happen on assignment of a function pointer to a function pointer lvalue, I think).

Comment: "isn't compiling" is not a known error message. Tell us the one you're actually getting. it probably has to do with the syntax of the type in your typedef, which looks nonsensical.

Comment: ; ( C++ ) main.cpp|25|error: invalid cast to function type ‘PSYS {aka int (*())(int, ...)}’|  function ‘int (* getpsys())(int, ...)’ is initialized like a variable|

Comment: What are the parens after PSYS supposed to represent? Not the arguments ... those are `(int,...)`.

Comment: the function looks like this int ( *function() ) (int,...){ return &systrig;}

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1096341/951890

Comment: Ok, I think you're trying to cast to a function, rather than a pointer to a function. Try using `PSYS*` instead of `PSYS`. ... See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PSYS is the type of a function, not a pointer to a function. You want

```
typedef  int ( *PSYS () ) (int,...);
PSYS* getf =  (PSYS*) dlsym(lib, "function" );
```

Comment: Geat, compil works, i'm just afraid about segfaults now ^^. Thank you

Comment: @Ododo Presumably it doesn't segfault on that line, but somewhere else. Good luck with your debugging. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If the symbol is a function pointer your typedef may be wrong.  Should be:

```
typedef int (*PSYS)(int, ...);
```

Comment: no, actually it is a function pointer returning a function pointer

Comment: So the symbol you are trying to get out is a function pointer returning a function pointer?  If so, that's wild.  So is it a utility function to get other functions in the library?

Comment: True, the other function is inline and can't be exported, but maybe there are other solutions.

Comment: Does this help?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758811/c-syntax-for-functions-returning-function-pointers