# understand block on programming with object C

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

on the tutorial promgrammingWithObjectiveC.

## The [following code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH8-SW5) make me confuse:

Custom type definitions are particularly useful when dealing with blocks that return blocks or take other blocks as arguments. Consider the following example:

```
void (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void) = ^ (void (^aBlock)(void)) {
    ...
    return ^{
        ...
    };
};
```

The complexBlock variable refers to a block that takes another block as an argument (aBlock) and returns yet another block.

Rewriting the code to use a type definition makes this much more readable:

```
typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);
XYZSimpleBlock (^betterBlock)(XYZSimpleBlock) = ^ (XYZSimpleBlock aBlock) {
    ...
    return ^{
        ...
    };
};
```

my understan the rewriting code : 
[image]
but I can't understand the source code:

```
void (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void) = ^ (void (^aBlock)(void)) {
    ...
    return ^{
        ...
    };
}
```

in my understand, it should be:

```
(void (^) (void)) (^complexBlock) (void (^)(void) = ^ (void (^aBlock)(void)) {
    ...
    return ^{
        ...
    };
};
```

Comment: Of _course_ it's confusing. It's a C declaration! They are hard to read and always have been. :)

Comment: `in my understand, it should be:` - no, why shouldn't it? Surely you know that blocks are declared similarly to functions. And that's not how the declaration of function return types work. Read a C book.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blocks are declared using syntax similar to that which is used to declare a pointer to a function, except that you use `^` instead of `*`.

So the function analogon would be a "pointer to a function that returns a function pointer",
which is nicely explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759352/1187415.

If you translate the "building procedure" of that answer to your block
then you get:

```
         complexBlock                          -- complexBlock
        ^complexBlock                          -- is a block
       (^complexBlock)(void (^)(void))         --   taking a block parameter
      ^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void))         --   returning a block
     (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void)  --     taking no parameters
void (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void)  --     returning void
```

More generally, there is a technique called the
["Clockwise/Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)
which you can use to "parse" a C declaration. The spiral rule works
for blocks as well.

Or use [cdecl C gibberish ↔ English](http://cdecl.org), which in [your case](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28%5E%28%5EcomplexBlock%29%28void+%28%5E%29%28void%29%29%29%28void%29)
returns

```
declare complexBlock as block (block (void) returning void) returning
block (void) returning void
```

Comment: Notice how Martin R develops his explanation of the declaration from the inside out, starting in the middle (the name) and then going outwards from there: one step left, one step right, one step left, one step right, one step left. That is how to read / write a C type declaration. And that's all a block type declaration is.

Comment: @matt: It's called "spiral rule" (link added to answer).

Comment: Great answer, Martin. Here's another nice reference to the spiral rule, applied to Objective-C block syntax http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/21/objective-c-blocks-syntax/