# Writing a function pointer in c

Tags: c, function, function-pointers

I was recently reading a code, and found that a function pointer is written as :

```
int (*fn_pointer ( this_args ))( this_args )
```

I usually encounter a function pointer like this :

```
return_type (*fn_pointer ) (arguments);
```

Similar thing is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work?rq=1):

```
// this is a function called functionFactory which receives parameter n
// and returns a pointer to another function which receives two ints
// and it returns another int
int (*functionFactory(int n))(int, int) {
printf("Got parameter %d", n);
int (*functionPtr)(int,int) = &addInt;
return functionPtr;
}
```

Can somebody tell me what is the difference and how does this work ?

Comment: can you please post the exact code? a compilable sample?

Comment: This might help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work?rq=1

Comment: @ iharob: My code is longer. I just updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int (*fn_pointer ( this_args ))( this_args );
```

declares `fn_pointer` as a function that takes `this_args` and returns a pointer to a function that takes `this_args` as argument and returns an `int` type. It is equivalent to

```
typedef int (*func_ptr)(this_args);
func_ptr fn_pointer(this_args);
```

Let's understand it a bit more:

```
int f1(arg1, arg2);  // f1 is a function that takes two arguments of type   
                     // arg1 and arg2 and returns an int.

int *f2(arg1, arg2);  // f2 is a function that takes two arguments of type  
                      // arg1 and arg2 and returns a pointer to int.  

int (*fp)(arg1, arg2); // fp is a pointer to a function that takes two arguments of type  
                       // arg1 and arg2 and returns a pointer to int.  

int f3(arg3, int (*fp)(arg1, arg2)); // f3 is a function that takes two arguments of  
                                        // type arg3 and a pointer to a function that 
                                        // takes two arguments of type arg1 and arg2 and 
                                        // returns an int.  

int (*f4(arg3))(arg1, arg2); // f4 is a function that takes an arguments of type   
                             // arg3 and returns a pointer to a function that takes two 
                             // arguments of type arg1 and arg2 and returns an int
```

[How to read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759352/2455888) `int (*f4(arg3))(arg1, arg2);`

```
          f4                           -- f4
        f3(   )                        -- is a function
        f3(arg3)                       --  taking an arg3 argument
       *f3(arg3)                       --   returning a pointer
     (*f3(arg3))(    )                 --   to a function
    (*f3(arg3))(arg1, arg2)            --     taking arg1 and arg2 parameter
  int (*f3(arg3))(arg1, arg2)           --     and returning an int
```

So, finally a home work :). Try to figure out the declaration

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

and use `typedef` to redefine it.

Comment: Which one is argument and which one is return ?

Answer (score 4):

From [cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) (which is a handy helper tool to decipher C declarations):

```
int (*fn_pointer ( this_args1 ))( this_args2 )
```

> declare fn_pointer as function (this_args1) returning pointer to
>   function (this_args2) returning int

Hence the former is a function, that returns pointer to function, while the latter:

`return_type (*fn_pointer ) (arguments);`

is an ordinary "pointer to function".

---

Read more about undestanding complex declarations from the [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) article.

Comment: `fn_pointer` is not a pointer in this declaration (just a function).

Answer (score 2):

This

```
int (*fn_pointer ( this_args1 ))( this_args2 )
```

declares a function that takes as arguments `this_args1` and returns a function pointer of type

```
int (*fn_pointer)(this_args2)
```

so it's just a function that returns a function pointer.