# What does this weird function pointer declaration in C mean?

Tags: c, function-pointers

Can anyone please explain what `int ((*foo(int)))(int)` in this does?

```
int (*fooptr)(int);
int ((*foo(int)))(int); // Can't understand what this does.

int main()
{
    fooptr = foo(0);
    fooptr(10);
}
```

.

Comment: Since no one has mentioned it, http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html. Remembering some simple rules allows you to easily unravel any declaration.

Comment: @chris; Not a universal rule. Fails in some cases.

Comment: @haccks: I can't think of any examples where it fails off the top of my head... Could you elaborate?

Comment: @wolfPack88; Aplly that rule on `int *a[2][3];`.

Comment: @haccks: Makes sense. Still, it's a simple modification to the rule, right? I.e., `[][]...[]` all need to be viewed as one block, and not separate. This gives you the right interpretation of `a` is an array of 2 arrays of 3 pointers to `int`.

Comment: @wolfPack88; Modification will make it worse. Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16265389/2455888).

Answer (score 37):

```
int ((*foo(int)))(int);
```

This declares `foo` as a function that expects an `int` type argument and returns a pointer to a function that expects an `int` type argument and return an `int`.

To be more clear:

```
          foo                           -- foo
        foo(   )                        -- is a function
        foo(int)                         --  taking an int argument
       *foo(int)                          --   returning a pointer
     (*foo(int))(  )                       --   to a function that
    (*foo(int))(int)                        --     takes an int argument
   int (*foo(int))(int)                      --     and returning an int
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759352/2455888) is a good explanation for the same.

Comment: Or to steal notation from another part of the world, it's an `int -> (int -> int)` function

Comment: @hobbs; Good. But not for beginners :)

Comment: @hobbs ML showed the way!

Answer (score 13):

```
foo
```

is what we declare.

```
foo(int)
```

It is a function that takes a single `int` argument

```
*foo(int)
```

and returns a pointer

```
((*foo(int)))(int)
```

to a function that takes a single `int` argument

```
int ((*foo(int)))(int)
```

and returns an `int`.

One pair of `()` is redundant. The same thing can be expressed as

```
int (*foo(int))(int)
```

Answer (score 8):

There already answers to this, but I wanted to approach it in the opposite way.

A function declaration looks the same as a variable declaration, except that the variable name is replaced by the function name *and parameters*.

So this declares `bar` as a pointer to a function that takes an `int` and returns an `int`:

```
int (*bar)(int);
```

If, instead of a variable `bar`, it's a function `foo(int)` with that return value, you replace `bar` with `foo(int)` and get:

```
int (*foo(int))(int);
//    ^^^^^^^^
// this was "bar" before
```

Add an unnecessary pair of parentheses and you get:

```
int ((*foo(int)))(int);
//   ^         ^
//  extra parentheses
```

Answer (score 6):

According to [cdecl](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+%28%28*foo%28int%29%29%29%28int%29%3B), `foo` is:

> declare foo as function (int) returning pointer to function (int) returning int

Comment: I often see on SO that cdecl link is provided in answers as a solution to explain complex pointer declarations. I think that's a problem in itself, not a solution. A C , C++ programmer should understand the basic logic behind these complex declaration and then after tools like cdecl can be used.

Comment: Contrariwise, if you are going to code `int ((*foo(int)))(int)` you could either comment it or compose it of more comprehensible typedefs. If I saw this in code review, I'd probably accuse the programmer of showing off. If it doesn't go without saying, showing off in code is a Bad, Stupid Thing.