# Syntax for declaring const member function returning a bare function pointer, without typedefs?

Tags: c++, function-pointers, member-functions, const-correctness

I have a class that stores a function pointer to some binary function

```
class ExampleClass
{
private:
    double(*_binaryFunction)(double, double);
}
```

How can I return this pointer in a const "getter"? This is either surprisingly hard to search for or nobody else has asked this. If the function weren't `const`, the syntax would be

```
double (*GetBinaryFunction())(double, double);
```

Where do I put the `const` qualifier? Like this?

```
double (*GetBinaryFunction() const)(double, double);
```

If I wanted to use a typedef, the syntax would be: (right?)

```
typedef double (*BinaryFunction)(double, double);
BinaryFunction GetBinaryFunction() const;
```

Not answering this question but still useful: [C syntax for functions returning function pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758811/c-syntax-for-functions-returning-function-pointers) (does not deal with const member functions)

Also I want to re-iterate that I don't want to return or am dealing with any pointer-to-member.

To address duplicates:
The more precise formulation of this question would be "**Where to syntactically put the cv-qualifier in the declaration of a member function returning a function pointer?**" The answer turned out to be surprising (in the middle of the declaration, not at the end as is usually the case) and none of the linked questions deal with the question of the `const` keyword position, only with broader syntax of function returning function pointer.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to make a type-alias, if it will make things so much easier?

Comment: As for your problem of where to place the `const`, you basically have only two alternatives. Why not simply try both of them and see what compiles?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In the end I did use it, but A: I was curious about this abomination and B: didn't want to leak the typedef out of the class, to introduce dependence somewhere.
And yes, I could (did) experiment and guessed it correctly but again, nobody else seems to have asked this before.

Comment: "the syntax would be" -- no, it wouldn't be. Try it. It won't work. `_binaryFunction` is not a function. It is a non-static class method. Non-static class methods cannot be converted to function pointers. Try every which way to convert it to a `double (*)(double, double)` -- it won't work. The question is based on a flawed premise.

Comment: @JanHošek what do you mean by "to leak the typedef" ? Isn't making it e.g. private good enough if you want to use it only for the implementation ?

Comment: @KamilCuk Yes, but i am asking about the syntax declaring the getter function. Of course the body is just `return _binaryFunction;`

Comment: @wohlstad I suppose that is another question, I wasn't very familiar with private typedefs in declarations of public functions but don't worry about that.

Comment: even when public, it doesn't "leak". It would be `ExampleClass::function_type` which cannot be confused with any other `function_type`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes of course but then somebody (lazy me) uses `ExampleClass::function_type` somewhere else where they could have used the "simple" function pointer and suddenly that place has dependence on example_class.h when it doesn't have to XD

Comment: if they need the type of the function pointer in `ExampleClass` and they are using `ExampleClass::function_type` then the type can change and the code using the alias is still using the right type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I return this pointer in a const "getter"?

Examples:

```
struct ExampleClass
{
    double (*_binaryFunction)(double, double);
    double (*GetBinaryFunction() const)(double, double) {
        return _binaryFunction;
    }

    typedef double (*BinaryFunctionTypedef)(double, double);
    BinaryFunctionTypedef GetBinaryFunction2() const {
        return _binaryFunction;
    }

    using binaryFunctionUsing = double (*)(double, double);
    binaryFunctionUsing GetBinaryFunction3() const {
        return _binaryFunction;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

To add upon what has been said, I think it's also important to mention the correct syntax for **references**.

---

- for the normal reference:

```
double (*&GetBinaryFunction())(double, double)
```

---

- and for the `const&` version:

```
double (*const& GetBinaryFunction() const)(double, double)
```

the first `const` describes the return type (a function pointer that is a `const` reference) and the second `const` describes the `ExampleClass` member constness.

---

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //for std::pow

class ExampleClass {
public:
    double (*&GetBinaryFunction())(double, double) {
        return this->_binaryFunction;
    }
    double (*const& GetBinaryFunction() const)(double, double) {
        return this->_binaryFunction;
    }

private:
    double(*_binaryFunction)(double, double);
};

void foo(ExampleClass& example, double a, double b) {

    example.GetBinaryFunction() = std::pow;

    std::cout << "foo( & ) : " << example.GetBinaryFunction()(a, b) << '\n';
}

void bar(const ExampleClass& example, double a, double b) {
    std::cout << "bar( const& ) : " << example.GetBinaryFunction()(a, b) << '\n';
}

int main() {
    ExampleClass example;
    foo(example, 2, 5);
    bar(example, 2, 6);
}
```

output:

```
foo( & ) : 32
bar( const& ) : 64
```

---

if you don't like the long syntax and don't want to use `typedef` or `using` you can also simply use `auto`:

```
auto& GetBinaryFunction() {
    return this->_binaryFunction;
}
const auto& GetBinaryFunction() const {
    return this->_binaryFunction;
}
```

it will compile into the same code as above. to not use reference, simple remove the `&` from the `auto`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `auto` return type

```
class ExampleClass
{
    auto get() const { return _binaryFunction; }
private:
    double(*_binaryFunction)(double, double);
};
```

Comment: @JanHošek nope https://godbolt.org/z/YfTv9zbn5

Comment: @JanHošek wtf what?!? Those questions are totally relevant, though I agree that they do not adress this question specifically about where to place the `const`. (neither does this answer ;)

Comment: Touché. I suppose I meant "in a .cpp file", a different translation unit?

Comment: sorry I didn't mean you specifically, just lamenting overzealous badge-chasing.

Comment: @JanHošek the comments on this answer are specifically for feedback on this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247710/discussion-between-jan-hosek-and-463035818-is-not-a-number).